# ASP.net MVC 4 Controller Functions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-controller

I have an application where I have to display data in a table format. The end user has four different ways they want this displayed so I have one model with different LINQ statements on each controller to manipulate the data. I have two shared views that hold the controls (filter options drop downs, text boxes, etc...) and the result set.

My question is this: How can I sub out repetitive functions? I have drop down boxes that I use to filter the result set and, forgive my ignorance, I call the same LINQ statement on each controller to load the ViewData for that drop down.

as you can see this is very inefficient, I have added a "UtlityController" to the project in hopes that I can place this function and a few others there, but still have the same output on the View... I haven't figured it out yet and thought I would reach out to the community for help.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: I am not sure code would help. Imagine you had 4 controllers all showing the same data but filtered slightly different and you needed the ability to alter and filter that data even more. the filtering controls are populated by void functions on your controller. I have the exact same function on each controller and I am trying to have that function in one location and call it from all four locations

Comment: Why do you have four controllers? For slight difference you can use different action method in same controller. Show us how your model looks like and how similar methods in different controller look like.

Comment: You could inherit all four controllers from your `UtilityController` and put the function in the base-class

Comment: @afzaluh I used four controllers because there are a few methods that differ between each other. Some have edit/delete/update functions that others do not.

Comment: @Kenneth can I share models and ViewData that way?

Comment: Why do you need to share ViewData? You can just call the function every time you pass a model to your view.

Comment: @Kenneth Thank you I see what you are saying now.